# Why name of reducer function is coming as a key in Component and how to pass multiple values in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to React and Redux and trying to build a simple Counter app with these technologies.

***Que.: 1***

The problem I am facing is, my Component prints `props` like below. I am not sure why the name of reducer function is coming as a `key`!

```
[Log] this.props.count>> – {counterReducerFunction: 0}
```

***Que. 2:***

How can I pass multiple values (not an array) from my state object to my Component? (Currently my Counter app has just one value i.e. count)

Below is my `code`:

**Reducer:**

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';

function counterReducerFunction(state, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return state + 1;
    case "DECREMENT":
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return 0;
  }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({counterReducerFunction});
export default rootReducer;
```

**Action:**

```
// Actions
export const INCREMENT = 'INCREMENT';
export const DECREMENT = 'DECREMENT';

// Action creators
function incrementCounter(state) {
  return {
    type: 'INCREMENT',
    count: state.count
  }
};

function decrementCounter(state) {
  return {
    type: 'DECREMENT',
    count: state.count
  }
};

export {incrementCounter, decrementCounter};
```

**Component:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {incrementCounter, decrementCounter} from './actions';


class Counter extends Component {

  render() {
    console.log('this.props.count>>', this.props.count); // this prints {counterReducerFunction: 0}


    return(
      <div>    
        <Button onClick={this.props.incrementCounter}>+</Button>
        <Button onClick={this.props.decrementCounter}>-</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    count: state
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {incrementCounter, decrementCounter})(Counter);
```

**App class:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Counter from './Counter';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
          <Counter />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

import {createStore} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

P.S.: This project structure has been created with [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)

> **Solution:** Changes done to `Reducer` make this work (Please refer to RIYAJ's
>   answer given below for more details):

**Reducer:**

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';

function counterReducerFunction(state = {count: 0}, action) {
  var countVar = state.count;
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return {count: countVar + 1};
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return {count: countVar - 1};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const rootReducer = counterReducerFunction;
export default rootReducer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **1. why-name-of-reducer-function-is-coming-as-a-key-in-component-?
>   In your reducers'**

`const rootReducer = combineReducers({counterReducerFunction});`

this statement create key for your state which `counterReducerFunction`.

If you dont want this key,then change it to

`const rootReducer = counterReducerFunction;` //remove combineReducers

It will not create key.

**Note :**

*As there is only one reducers  you have,you can remove `combineReducers`.But when there is multiple reducers,you must have to use`combineReducers` and it will create key for each reducers.So,for accessing the state,you need to use the specific reducers key*

> **2. How can I pass multiple values (not an array) from my state object to my Component?**

As per current implementation,your state variable initialise to 0 
because of `return 0` statement in reducers for default action. For default action.,it always should be `state` object.

So,that's why you are getting 0 in console statement.

Your reducers should be like this.

```
function counterReducerFunction(state={}, action) { //initilize state to default
  switch(action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return {counter : state.counter + action.counter , ...state}; //you can add addition properties here.
    case "DECREMENT":
      return {counter : state.counter - action.counter , ...state};//you can add addition properties here.
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

`action` object will carry some data (`counter`) when you dispatch INCREMENT and DECREMENT action.

```
dispatch({type:INCREMENT,counter:1}) //INCREMENT action
dispatch({type:DECREMENT,counter:1}) //DECREMENT action
```

Comment: When I use like: const rootReducer = combineReducers(counterReducerFunction); Then I get error: "Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers"

Comment: @AkshayLokur I have corrected ans.As there is only one reducers have,you have to remove `combineReducers`.But when there is multiple reducers,you must have to use`combineReducers` and it will create key for each reducers.So,for accessing the state,you need to use the specific reducers key

Comment: Thanks, this helped. In addition, I had to pass Object with "count" variable to my reducer as argument: "function counterReducerFunction(state = {count: 0}, action) {" ... Cheers!

Comment: yes,you can if you want to initialise it to some default state.

Answer (score 0):

In one place you are accessing `state` and in another place you are accessing `state.count`

This should become:

`function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    count: state.count
  };
}`

I would also recommend you initialize your state in your function like so:

`function counterReducerFunction(state = {}, action) {`